# LoadError in StoreController#add_to_cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails using Agile Web Development with Rails third edition and I am completely stuck.  I am using Ruby version 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5 on Linux Mint.  Just after the book recommended that I change from cookies to the SQLite database to manage sessions, the application no longer works.  I get the following error when I click on the “add to cart” button in http://localhost:3000/store:

LoadError in StoreController#add_to_cart
Expected /home/dave/work/depot/app/models/cart.rb to define Cart
RAILS_ROOT: /home/dave/work/depot
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_support/dependencies.rb:426:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in`const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_support/dependencies.rb:437:in`load_missing_constant'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_support/dependencies.rb:96:in `const_missing'
/home/dave/work/depot/app/controllers/store_controller.rb:14:in`find_cart'
/home/dave/work/depot/app/controllers/store_controller.rb:8:in `add_to_cart'
Request
Parameters:
{"authenticity_token"=>"38s45mRICYPJ7dw+z/rlcBnQN7T8ZwfEThzUTFUrjeM=",
 "id"=>"3"}
Show session dump
Response
Headers:
{"Content-Type"=>"",
 "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}

```
   def add_product(product)
     current_item = @items.find {|item| item.product == product}
     if current_item
       current_item.increment_quantity
     else
       @items << CartItem.new(product)
     end
   end
```

I have done a search on this in Google and a similar error seems to be related to utf-8 encoding.  I used Gedit to save the file as Western (ISO 8859-15) encoding and it made no difference.  I have also retyped the programs in Vi to no avail.  Each time I have made a change, I have stopped and restarted the server and also entered db:sessions:clear into a terminal.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your app/models/cart.rb , it should be like this

```
 class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

 #stuff here 
 end
```

make sure its that.

Answer (score 1):

This error tends to occur when there is an error in the file being loaded. One way to figure this out is to run:

```
ruby script/console
```

... then:

```
Cart
```

This should either load up the model OK, or output a more useful error.